# Autocomplete jQuery Plugin : Value of selected array index

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How do I get the value of the index position in the array, whose element the user had chosen using the autocomplete?

For e.g. if I enter the array having two elements as the input for the autocomplete plugin:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "John";
arr[1] = "Paul";
```

Then, say user selects "Paul", how do I get the value of the selected index "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you could just do something like

```
function FindIndex( arr, searchValue ){
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i ){
        if( arr[i] === searchValue ){
            return i;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can also do that with the jQuery find() method.  http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr

Answer (score 1):

jQuery way:
If your autocompletion source is a plain array (i.e. not an array of label-value pairs or URL), then you can do

```
$.inArray(ui.item.value,myAutocompleteSource)
```

e.g.

> ```
>        $('.my-autocompletes').autocomplete({
>                   source:['Option1','Option2','Option3'],
>                   select: function(event, ui) {
>                     alert('Your selected a string with index '+
>                      $.inArray(ui.item.value,$(_self).autocomplete('option','source'))
>                     );
>               }
>         });
> ```

If the source IS an array of label-value pairs, then you can do

```
var index = -1;
$(_self).autocomplete('option','source')).each(function(idx) { 
       if (this.label == ui.item.label) { index=idx; return false; }
});
alert('You selected a string with index '+index);
```

Of course, `$(_self).autocomplete('option','source'))` can be replaced with a direct reference to the source of autocomplete items.

Answer (score 0):

This ref http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val#val
says you can use  a selector like so:

```
$('#selection option:selected')....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "John";
arr[1] = "Paul";
...
//user selects something
//assuming select value now is in an input field
var index = jQuery.inArray($("input#yourselector").val(), arr);
if (index > -1)
    alert(index);
else
    alert("value not found in autocomplete array");
```