# Get index of JQuery UI autocomplete element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI with a text box. When the user selects from the drop down list of possible matches, I want to get the index of the selection from the source array, assuing a JavaScript array.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This question has already been asked for an array of string here : [Autocomplete jQuery Plugin : Value of selected array index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929836/autocomplete-jquery-plugin-value-of-selected-array-index) Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log($.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags));
}
```

where availableTags is the autocomplete's source array.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mf8vU/)**